# Defining Datatemplates in code

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control where I have resources defined in Generic.xaml. I need to create data templates at run time e.g.

```
xaml = "<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding " + Binding + "}\"/></DataTemplate>";
```

This works fine, however if the template accesses other resources I'm stuck e.g.

```
xaml = "<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding " + Binding +
                      "}\" Margin=\"{Binding Bar, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Foo}}}\"/></DataTemplate>";
```

Both the converter and the RelativeSource will cause problems.

Either "Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'local:Foo'." or
"Cannot find resource named 'MyConverter'." If the data template I'm trying to create in code is instead defined in the Generic.xaml and is selected with a TemplateSelector it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to defined the resources in datatemplate.

```
 <DataTemplate xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Please convert it to C# support format.